# How to calculate maximum wind speed in a funnel (Venturi Effect)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, air, speed

It must be in an open area, so nothing forces the wind, just himself. Lets assume that the wind is blowing only one direction. I assume that at some point the speed will stop increasing and it will stop entering the funnel because of the pressure, is that assumption right?

What would be the major factor that will cap the speed? Initial speed probably is the most important, also exit size, because you can't speed the wind 10 times its original speed (not in an open area).

Let me know if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a funnel cloud.

Comment: No... Just a funnel. Pic: https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYJO1yrpSxf26EwUu_CK89ZRGioWHfXINPVTzDr_XHiT6D8Zml

Comment: Could you comment why you put the Venturi Effect in the header? Do you want the answer based on this model. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on what you already did to find this out.